# Scala Monocle - Cannot find method id in E

Tags: scala, monocle

The class definition looks like this:

```
abstract class EntityWithIdHelper[E <: { def id: Int }] {
  def idLens: Lens[E, Int] = GenLens[E](_.id)
  ...
```

How do you avoid this problem - `Cannot find method id in E`? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot create a `Lens` for `id` because a `Lens` requires a getter and a setter and here you only have a getter.

Also if you want to use `GenLens[E]`, `E` has to be a case class.